# Do constructor arguments get GC'ed?

Tags: scala, constructor, garbage-collection

I am using a system which needs to initialize many objects using transactions, and for reasons beyond the scope of this question these transactions must be passed into the constructors. Like this:

```
trait Mutable

class Txn(i: Int) {
  def newID(implicit m: Mutable): Int = i
  override def finalize(): Unit = println("Finalised " + i)
}

class User(t0: Txn) extends Mutable {
  val id = t0.newID(this)
}
```

Now I am fearing there is a problem with garbage collecting the transactions:

```
val u = new User(new Txn(1234))
System.gc()  // hmmm, nothing seems to happen?
```

So my question is: Does the `t0` constructor argument ever get garbage collected, or do I create a memory leak here? In an equivalent Java code, I guess I'd have something like this:

```
public class User implements Mutable {
    final int id;
    public User(Txn t0) {
        id = t0.newID(this);
    }
}
```

and I am sure `t0` is collected. But is this true in the Scala case?

If not, how can I ensure `t0` is garbage collected? Remember that I *must* pass in the transaction as a constructor argument, because the `User` class implements some traits which must be passed into `Txn`'s methods, thus those methods (like `newID`) cannot be called before constructing `User`.

I have tried before to construct everything that uses the transaction outside of the user object, with tons of `lazy` interdependent vals, but that was really messy. For example, this, which is already halfway unreadable, produces a stack overflow:

```
trait User extends Mutable { def id: Int }

def newUser(implicit tx: Txn): User = {
  lazy val _id: Int = tx.newID(u)
  lazy val u  = new User { val id: Int = _id } // oops, should be lazy val id!
  u
}

val u = newUser(new Txn(1234))
```

You can imagine that it really sucks that the compiler won't spot the problem with the missing lazy val here, so I would definitely prefer the constructor arg variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If absolutely necessary, I recommend you use `javap` to see what the class has compiled into. Some rules to avoid getting the constructor argument turned into a class parameter:

- Don't use it on `def` or `lazy val`.
- Don't use it on assignment that do pattern matches (like `val (a, b) = f(x)`).
- And, of course, do not declare it as `val` or `var`.

Comment: Checking is perhaps the best advice!  The easiest way to check is usually to use the `-private` flag in javap, and not worry about bytecode.  That will list the private fields first (using Java syntax), which will include something like `x$1` for constructor arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Constructor arguments get GCed *if they are not used beyond the static initializer*.  You can check the bytecode and verify that no reference to the constructor argument is preserved in this case.

```
class WillNotStore(s: Seq[Int]) { val length = s.length }

public WillNotStore(scala.collection.Seq);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #18; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aload_1
   6:   invokeinterface #22,  1; //InterfaceMethod scala/collection/SeqLike.length:()I
   11:  putfield    #11; //Field length:I
   14:  return
```

Note that the argument is loaded (line 5) and a method is called on it (line 6), but only the answer is stored (line 11) before the constructor quits (line 14).

Comment: Hah! I just told him to use javap, and here you are using it to answer his question. :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - `scala -cp /path/to/tools.jar` + `:javap -c WillNotStore` only takes a few seconds....

Comment: @Sciss - Daniel's answer is more complete; the pattern match _even in the initializer_ is a strange special case that I had forgotten.  `DelayedInit` is another (though it's more obviously necessary there, since it works conceptually like `lazy val`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had seemed to be with a particular situation where `System.gc()` wouldn't really kick in straight away.

But I can observe the finalisation taking place in a plain REPL, and also in some compiled code, so I guess the answer is, 'yes, the constructor argument does get garbage collected'.

It also works when passing through super classes, which is further good news:

```
abstract class Underlying(t0: Txn) extends Mutable {
  val id1 = t0.newID(this)
}

class User(t0: Txn) extends Underlying(t0) {
   val id2 = t0.newID(this)
}
```